# Reply to specific message in Chat reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to implement a feature in a chat that will allow one to reply to a specific message (like how WhatsApp does it ) in reactjs. I was hoping if anyone has implemented it before can help me out

Comment: hey sir please do some further research about how chatting is done in react iam sure u will find good tutorials on youtube ,  try and if you got some issues edit the above question and update , then the community will help  thanks.

Comment: if i had found what i was looking for i  wouldn't be here

Comment: ok cool are u comfortable with reactjs if yes i will recommend a good tutorial

Comment: I am it is what am using to implement. Please do recommend

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay . here its "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HggSXt1Hzfk&t=5278s" hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Replying to specific users?
In programming world every entity have some unique id.
For example the user which send you message he send to your id.
In API terms it will be like this, if you are using a REST API -

```
https://chat-api-sever.com/sendmsg/{userid}
```

Same goes for reply also

```
https://chat-api-sever.com/reply/{msgid}/{userid}
```